# Create installer for Office VSTO add-in for deployment system

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, ms-office, vsto, outlook-addin

I have this working Office VSTO add-in, that is installed from the web (download a setup.exe file, that then connects to the hosted .vsto file an gets all the necessary things), however I have a request to wrap it in some sort of installer, so it can be installed on computers, where the users don't have download & install privileges.

They will then use a deployment system, to deploy the add-in on the machines.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Do I have to take the registry paths into consideration? Whether it should be for current user, or local machine? Or that should be taken care of automatically by the MSI installer?

Also, how would updates be delivered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently went through the installation of a VSTO Add In using an MSI. Hopefully this will be of some help to you.

Assuming you use Visual Studio, [use this following guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer).

In terms of Local Machine and Current User – It doesn't matter which you choose, so long as you use the correct registry values.

If you follow the guide that I have posted you will have everything you need to run the MSI and install successfully.

If you need any assistance throughout this, get in touch with me in the comments below and I will do my best to help.

Comment: Will this create one MSI file, that would be compatible with multiple Office/Windows bit scenarios? (like 32bit Office with 64 bit windows, 32bit Office with 32bit Windows, and 64bit Office with 64bit Windows)

Comment: Yes, this will create one MSI file. The installer will be compatible with all of the variations, you will just need to specify the correct registry keys for those versions.

This can be done rather simply by adding the required registry values in the " registry keys " section of the MSI creation tool ( installshield )

I can show you exactly where the registry keys need to be installed if you aren't sure. Basically you will need to add the required keys to the Wow6432Node section of the registry. The guide does touch on the exact location too.

Comment: Thank you Ross! I've went with WIX for this, because I had a deadline, but I will go with the tutorial you mentioned here for the next project, because it seems much easier!

Comment: You're welcome. I spent a lot of time working on my own installer as I had a few issues with it, if you get stuck anywhere in future post it here and Ill help you if I can.

Comment: Hi, My problem is when I install the add-in msi using psexec64.exe , registry keys are in the correct place but outlook fails to load the add-in on Outlook 2010, 2013. But it loads up properly on Outlook 2016. Any idea ?

Comment: Any idea how to require that Word is closed before the installation proceeds? Otherwise the addin will not install correctly.

Comment: @Laureant Can you share how you configured WiX to accomplish this?

Comment: I currently ran into problems with an Office 365 'MS Store' - Version. The registry keys have changed and it seems, they are stored as separate .reg-files in a subfolder of c:\program files\WindowsApps\.
Does anyone have a glue about that specific pre-inslalled version of Office?